# How to prevent two buttons being tapped at the same time in swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

In swift or objective-c, I can set exclusiveTouch property to true or YES, but how do I do it in swiftUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be handled something like below :

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isEnabled = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            Button(action: {
                self.isEnabled.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Button 1")
            }
            .padding(20)                
            .disabled(isEnabled)


            Button(action: {
                self.isEnabled.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Button 2")
            }
            .padding(50)
            .disabled(!isEnabled)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to enable these buttons after clicking one of them? Adding a timer?

Comment: Yes. Tapping the enabled button will make it disabled while enabling the other one.  Regarding the timer, that is not part of the initial question.

Comment: Both need to be enabled. And prevent multitouch.

Comment: @FRIDDAY Sample provided is to give an idea on how to enable one while the other should be in disabled state.  Question has been changed since it was answered.

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode 11.3**

Set `exclusiveTouch` and `isMultipleTouchEnabled` properties inside your struct `init()` or place it in `AppDelegate.swift` for the whole app:

```
struct ContentView: View {

init() {

        UIButton.appearance().isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
        UIButton.appearance().isExclusiveTouch = true

        UIView.appearance().isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
        UIView.appearance().isExclusiveTouch = true

        //OR

        for subView in UIView.appearance().subviews {

            subView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
            subView.isExclusiveTouch = true

            UIButton.appearance().isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
            UIButton.appearance().isExclusiveTouch = true
        }
    }

var body: some View {

VStack {
     Button(action: {
                print("BTN1")
            }){
                Text("First")
            }

     Button(action: {
                print("BTN2")
            }){
                Text("Second")
            }
   }  
 }
}
```