# how to make swiftUI buttons exclusive?

Tags: swiftui

using swiftUI i have a lot of Buttons which i need to make only one can be clicked at the same time.
By default in swiftUI  you have two or more buttons on a view you can click them all at once
I tried adding the following:

```
            UIButton.appearance().isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
            UIButton.appearance().isExclusiveTouch = true
```

With UIKit we had exclusiveTouch and MultiTouchEnabled but how do we do this with swiftUI?
What is the correct way to solve this application wide?

Update: The use case is simple there is a view with a login button and a register button and now the user can tap both at the same time which i don't want

Comment: May be you could explain what the use case

Comment: There isn't a whole lot of information in this question, but perhaps this will help?

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58825232/how-to-prevent-two-buttons-being-tapped-at-the-same-time-in-swiftui)